# Custom Checkboxes using Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firefox, checkbox

I'm trying to add custom checkboxes that will also work in firefox, but I'm having trouble with the ruby-code. What I want is something along those lines:

```
    <%= f.check_box :privacy_statement_accepted, id:"agb" %>
    <%= f.label :privacy_statement_accepted, "<span></span>".html_safe %>
```

However, this code disables the use of the checkbox and returns always true, but if I change it to:

```
    <%= f.check_box :privacy_statement_accepted, {:checked=>false}, id:"agb" %>
    <%= f.label :privacy_statement_accepted, "<span></span>".html_safe %>
```

it doesn't update the value when the box is checked. Is there a solution that uses f.check_box and not check_boxe_tag?

This is what I'm using atm because it works but it is not great:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agb" name="privacy_statement_accepted" />
<label for="agb"><span></span></label>
```

The CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    font-size:14px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(icons/checkbox.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:hover + label span {
    background:url(icons/checkbox.png) left bottom -20px no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(icons/checkbox.png) left top -46px no-repeat;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
function validateAgb() {
if ($('#agb').is(':checked')) {
    $('#agbMsg').hide();
    return true;
} else {
    $('#abg').focus();
    $('#agbMsg').show();
    return false;
}
}
```

Thanks!